# On a Clojure/Clojurescript project, does it make sense to have dependencies declared on a "shadow-cljs.edn" and a "deps.edn" file?

Tags: clojure, dependencies, clojurescript, leiningen, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

In one of the private repositories, there is a `deps.edn` file with the following content:

```clj
{:deps
 {org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.10.3"},
  reagent {:mvn/version "0.10.0"},
  org.clojure/tools.logging {:mvn/version "1.1.0"},
  org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.866"}, 
  ring {:mvn/version "1.9.0"}, 
  garden {:mvn/version "1.3.10"}, 
  metosin/malli {:mvn/version "0.5.1"}, 
  hiccup {:mvn/version "1.0.5"}, 
  metasoarous/oz {:mvn/version "1.6.0-alpha35"}, 
  re-frame {:mvn/version "0.12.0"}}
```

At the same time, there is another file `shadow-cljs.edn` with the following definition:

```clj
 :dependencies
 [[reagent "1.1.0"]
  [re-frame "1.2.0"]
  [day8.re-frame/tracing "0.6.2"]
  [garden "1.3.10"]
  [metosin/malli "0.8.3"]
  [binaryage/devtools "1.0.3"]
  [day8.re-frame/re-frame-10x "1.1.11"]]
```

As you see, some things such as `reagent` appear on both files and they use different versions!

This feels weird to me. But the project seems to work fine.

Why does this happen? Where is each version of, say, `reagent`used? Is there a better way to declare the dependencies?

;; UPDATE

User @E[ugenePakhomov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564509/eugene-pakhomov) gave a nice answer to this post. The code is an attempt to implement his suggestion.

Hence, I did:

```clj
{:deps
 {reagent {:mvn/version "0.10.0"},
  re-frame {:mvn/version "0.12.0"},
  garden {:mvn/version "1.3.10"},
  metosin/malli {:mvn/version "0.5.1"},
  org.clojure/tools.logging {:mvn/version "1.1.0"},
  org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.866"}, 
  ring {:mvn/version "1.9.0"}, 
  hiccup {:mvn/version "1.0.5"}, 
  metasoarous/oz {:mvn/version "1.6.0-alpha35"}, 
  org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.10.3"},

  {:alias {:cljs-only-dependencies
             reagent {:mvn/version "1.1.0"},
             re-frame {:mvn/version "1.2.0"},
             day8.re-frame/tracing {:mvn/version "0.6.2"},
             garden {:mvn/version "1.3.10"},
             metosin/malli {:mvn/version "0.8.3"},
             binaryage/devtools {:mvn/version "1.0.3"},
             day8.re-frame/re-frame-10x} {:mvn/version "1.1.11"}}}

 :source-paths ["src" "test"]}
```

Is this the correct implementation of your suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shadow-cljs uses those dependencies to build your CLJS code. And the `deps.edn` dependencies are used to run your CLJ code.

Those two things aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. E.g. you can have some CLJS code using some macros that are written in CLJ and that rely on some dependencies - in that case, such dependencies will have to be specified in both files.

An alternative to that layout that avoids duplication is to specify `:deps true` in `shadow-cljs.edn` and move all the dependencies from there into `deps.edn`. Even better, move all CLJS-only dependencies under some specific alias and use `:deps {:aliases [:that-alias]}` - this way, your CLJ code won't even know about CLJS-only dependencies so they won't pollute the classpath.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question to display my implementation of your suggestion. If you have time to check if my understanding is correct, that would be awesome.

Comment: @PedroDelfino Almost - `deps.edn` has 3 relevant top-level keys: `:deps`, `:aliases`, `:paths`. Also, each alias is a map of keys similar to the ones you have at the top level, although usually `:deps` there is replaced with `:extra-deps`. Like here: https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli#extra_deps